# fstrim.service blocks trim of /home in Ubuntu/Mint v20, but not in v18

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, systemd, fstrim

In troubleshooting why my /home partition (ext4, luks-encrypted) wasn't being trimmed by the weekly **fstrim** service, I discovered that Ubuntu made a major change in the service file:

**On Ubuntu/Mint 18**

```
[Unit]
Description=Discard unused blocks
ConditionVirtualization=!container

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/fstrim -av
```

**On Ubuntu/Mint 20**

```
[Unit]
Description=Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstrim(8)
ConditionVirtualization=!container

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/fstrim --fstab --verbose --quiet
ProtectSystem=strict
ProtectHome=yes
PrivateDevices=no
PrivateNetwork=yes
PrivateUsers=no
ProtectKernelTunables=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
SystemCallFilter=@default @file-system @basic-io @system-service
```

Can someone please explain why the change? I can, of course, manually change the `ProtectHome=yes` setting to `ProtectHome=no`. But why was this introduced in the latest Ubuntu? Is there a problem trimming /home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the result of [over-enthusiastic hardening](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/8f3d2d76aa3f5e20313362db6669dcd001bff26c#diff-e8efd1debf0d80db07a9f77d9605fdc7acfec626f4063f9c0aed540de78f5607), and has since been fixed, in two steps:

- [first set to `read-only`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/824)
- [then removed entirely](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/948)

You should override the service (`sudo systemctl edit fstrim`) and set the `ProtectSystem` and `ProtectHome` entries to `no`.

Comment: OK, thanks for this. LM 20 is still using v2.34. One quick question: is my **ProtectHome=no** safe, or should I use the examples in your links?

Comment: `ProtectHome=no` is safe.